# Van Kampen colimits

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

[nLab](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/van+Kampen+colimit) uses the following definition of van Kampen colimits --- a colimit in a category $\mathbb{C}$ is called van Kampen iff it is preserved by the internal indexing functor $\mathbb{C}/(-) \colon \mathbb{C}^{op} \rightarrow \mathbf{Cat}$ defined as:
$$X \mapsto \mathbb{C}/X$$
$$X \overset{f}\rightarrow Y \mapsto  \mathbb{C}/Y \overset{f^*}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}/X$$
where $f^*$ is the pullback-along-$f$ functor.

My question is --- where does this definition come from and why are such colimits called "van Kampen"?

In case of coproducts one may notice that the property of being van Kampen in the above sense is equivalent to the usual property of being extensive.

On the other hand, van Kampen pushouts in the above sense do not match the usual definition of van Kampen pushouts from the definition of an adhesive category. For example, if $\mathbb{C} = \mathbf{Set}$ then the internal indexing functor $\mathbf{Set}/(-)$ is equivalent to the usual exponential functor $\mathbf{Set}^{(-)}$, which (like every exponential functor) preserves all colimits; but not every pushout in $\mathbf{Set}$ is van Kampen (pushouts along monomorphisms are).

Comment: http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.4594 ?

Comment: The exponential functor $\mathbf{Set}^{(-)}$ does not send colimits of sets to 2-limits of categories. For example, consider the coequalizer of the diagram $*\rightrightarrows *$.

Comment: In fact, the only locally presentable category in which all colimits are van Kampen is the terminal category, since such a category must be an $\infty$-topos.

Comment: @MarcHoyois, right --- because colimits in Set are not the same as colimits in Cat. Silly me :-)

Comment: @MarcHoyois, no, wait, I'm having hard moments today --- we are talking about discrete colimits, which are the same as in Cat (since the inclusion Set ---> Cat is left adjoint). So, what is your counterexample? BTW, we do not have to talk about 2-limits in Cat, because every limit in Cat is automatically a 2-limit.

Comment: Maybe your notion of 2-limit is different. According to the nLab definition http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-limit, the inclusion Set → Cat does not preserve 2-colimits: the 2-colimit of $*\rightrightarrows *$ in Cat is the groupoid $B\mathbb{Z}$. Hence, the 2-limit of $Set\rightrightarrows Set$, where both arrows are the identity, is the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-sets.

Comment: @MarcHoyois It appears to me that Michal R. Przybylek is talking about 2-(co)limits in the classical sense of ($\mathbf{Cat}$-)enriched category theory, whereas you are talking about bi(co)limits.

Comment: @ZhenLin, MarcHoyois --- that's right. Somehow I thought that if you strictify a pseudofunctor, then the concept of limits strictifies automatically. But it seems that it strictifies only in one direction. Hm... I just have unlearned something...

Comment: If you post your observations as an answer than I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: If you want to remove your question from the unanswered list by providing a CW answer yourself (which is a good idea if it was answered in the comments), I suggest summarizing what the answer to the question is. Your current answer does answer the question and may be deleted because of that. If some comments answer your question, you can copy the comments to your answer (with suitable attribution and reformatting).

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, I am afraid some people are overenthusiastic about the moderation toolbox. Yes, I wanted to remove the question from both "unanswered" and "open" question lists. In fact, I would have deleted the question itself, if it were not for Marc Hoyois, who offered me his time. I think it is fair to keep the track of the conversation. On the other hand, it is clear that my question based on some terminological confusion and therefore, strictly speaking, it cannot be answered --- because there can be no answer to a no-question.

Comment: If the question is based on a confusion, telling exactly what the confusion was is a good answer. A question can be nonsensical in a strict sense (due to a confusion or a soft formulation) but still useful. I think such questions can (and should, provided they are otherwise good) be answered, although answering doesn't mean the same thing as for some other questions. There seems to be a confusion worth clarifying here, and an answer would probably convey that best to a future reader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a summary of the comments above (which does not answer the question on the origin of the term, that I have no idea).

A colimit in a category $C$ with pullbacks is van Kampen if the indexing functor $C/(-): C^{op} \to Cat$ transforms it into a *weak* 2-limit, or bilimit, or homotopy limit. These are sometimes called 2-limit or simply limit, but the latter also have stricter meanings which do not give the correct definition.

This is a very strong property: a locally presentable category (or even a locally presentable $(n,1)$-category for any finite $n$) in which all small colimits are universal and all pushouts are van Kampen is necessarily the terminal category, because it [must be](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/van+Kampen+colimit#InHigherCategories) an $\infty$-topos.

For $C=Set$, for example, the coequalizer of $*\rightrightarrows *$ is not van Kampen, because the weak 2-limit of $Set\rightrightarrows Set$ is the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-sets rather than the category of sets. A colimit in $Set$ is van Kampen iff its category of elements is simply connected. Pushouts have this property if one of the legs is injective, although that's not necessary.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that last paragraph? I don't see how the category of elements for a coproduct is simply connected. What functor are we even talking about?

Comment: I misspoke, the condition is that every connected component of the category of elements should be simply connected. The category of elements of a functor $F: C\to Set$ is the category of pairs $(c,x)$ with $x\in F(c)$. The homotopy type $X$ of this category is the colimit of $F$ in spaces. So the colimit of $F$ in $Set$ is van Kampen iff $Fun(X,Set)=Fun(\pi_0(X),Set)$, which is true iff every component of $X$ is simply connected.